# Atom with Typescript jquery issue

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, atom-editor

I'm having several issues whilst attempting to begin editing a large workplace project using GitHub's Atom Editor with Typescript instead of Visual Studio.

1. My JavaScript functions are not recognized unless I convert all of my JavaScript to `.ts` files, my system has 100+ JS files of which ideally I would like to leave as is, is it possible to to develop new files in TypeScript whilst leaving all my old JS files as is, without the editor complaining the functions do not exist?
2. jQuery apparently does not exist, We use `aspx` pages and a `Site.Master` template file which define the jQuery location using

   ```
   <script src="/scripts/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
   ```

I'm guessing the Atom Editor cannot understand the site master page and therefore does not think jQuery exists. This is holding back development any easy way to get this recognized?

[image: Project Layout Image]

> Note: This isn't a node project or anything complicated, simply a bunch of HTML(.aspx) pages with a bunch of JS files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert any of your js files, but anywhere you want to use one of your JavaScript functions from another file, you need to do an ambient declaration like this:

```
declare var myFunction: any;
```

This lets TypeScript know that there's some function named `myFunction` available for you to use, and don't worry about it's type, just let me use it however I want. You could do the same for jQuery, but there are type definition files for popular libraries like jQuery, so you can get the TypeScript intellisense for them. You can install them with [Typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings). It's a command line tool that for installing type definition files. Once you have Typings installed, run the following command to install the jQuery definition file:

```
typings install jquery --ambient --save
```

If you're using Visual Studio 2015, you can also use the [Package Installer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/753b9720-1638-4f9a-ad8d-2c45a410fd74), which supports installing type definition files with Typings. It doesn't install Typings for you though. You have to install it yourself first.